# How to whitelist URL from NGINX config file?

Tags: nginx, webserver

I would like to be able to whitelist certain IPs in my NGINX config file and deny everything else. This way I can be certain that only the IPs I allow can access my website.

I've already done this and it's working. In the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file, I've added the following:

```
server {
 allow ip address; #comment
 allow ip address; #comment
 deny all;
}
```

The problem that we've is we listen to Shopify webhook notifications to our web app to certain URLs and Shopify uses various IP addresses for this, 614 found so far and still counting. Whitelisting these many IP addresses without certainty that there will be no more is not looking like a solution. But if we can keep open the couple of URLs that Shopify sends notification to in our web app, that will solve our problem. This way, we don't have to worry about whitelisting IPs that Shopify uses to send webhook notification.

So what I am looking for is to keep these couple of URLs open to any IPs. Everything else except for the ip we whitelist and the URLs we choose to keep open will be blocked.

If this is not possible and there is alternative solution to this problem, please advise. Thank you.